# How to improve loading time in case user will have a lot of data in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, antd

I have a lot of data and Now I am facing, a lot of issue, due to large amount of data the app performance is slow, and it took a lot of time to load the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you can split your data with pagination API, you can use the next approach. And get only part of the data.
For instance:

`https://your-api.com/all-data?pageNumber=1&pageSize=10` - get only ten elements

then when the next part will be needed call next page

`https://your-api.com/all-data?pageNumber=2&pageSize=10`

Of course, you need to implement this API on your server